# more than one function for same change event of drop down list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 drop down list. 1 is for selecting department.  second is selecting subject. this drop down should be populated based on department drop down. third is student drop down. this should also populated based on department drop down. how can i perform this? Any help???

```
 $(function () {
        var items = '<option>Select Subject</Option>';
        $('#DepartmentID').change(function () {

            $.getJSON('/Mark/SubjectList/' + $('#DepartmentID').val(), function (data) {

                $.each(data, function (i, subject) {
                    items += "<option value='" + subject.Value + "'>" + subject.Text + "</option>";
                });
                alert("changed");
                $('#SubjectID').html(items);
            });

        });
    });


$(function () {
        var items = '<option>Select Subject</Option>';
        $('#DepartmentID').change(function () {

            $.getJSON('/Mark/StudentList/' + $('#DepartmentID').val(), function (data) {

                $.each(data, function (i, student) {
                    items += "<option value='" + student.Value + "'>" + student.Text + "</option>";
                });

                $('#StudentID').html(items);
            });

        });
    });
```

these are the two functions that I want to combine.

Comment: What's the difference between the two functions other than `alert()` in the first function?

Comment: the IDs are different. alert is added just for testing

Answer (score 1):

Just put both AJAX calls within one change handler for `DepartmentID`:

```
$(function () {
    $('#DepartmentID').change(function () {

        $.getJSON('/Mark/SubjectList/' + $('#DepartmentID').val(), function (data) {

            var items = '<option>Select Subject</Option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, subject) {
                items += "<option value='" + subject.Value + "'>" + subject.Text + "</option>";
            });
            alert("changed");
            $('#SubjectID').html(items);
        });


        $.getJSON('/Mark/StudentList/' + $('#DepartmentID').val(), function (data) {

            var items = '<option>Select Subject</Option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, student) {
                items += "<option value='" + student.Value + "'>" + student.Text + "</option>";
            });

            $('#StudentID').html(items);
        });

    });
});
```

(Note: I did also move the `var items = ...` bit inside each respective callback function so they each have their own variable. I suspect one was supposed to say "Select Student")

This code will now make 2 AJAX requests whenever `DepartmentID` dropdown is changed, a populates 2 different `select` elements

Answer (score 0):

Just combine this way:

```
$(function () {
  var items = '<option>Select Subject</Option>';
  $('#DepartmentID').change(function () {
    $.getJSON('/Mark/SubjectList/' + $('#DepartmentID').val(), function (data) {
      $.each(data, function (i, subject) {
        items += "<option value='" + subject.Value + "'>" + subject.Text + "</option>";
      });
      alert("changed");
      $('#SubjectID').html(items);
    });
  });
  var stuitems = '<option>Select Subject</Option>';
  $('#DepartmentID').change(function () {
    $.getJSON('/Mark/StudentList/' + $('#DepartmentID').val(), function (data) {
      $.each(data, function (i, student) {
        stuitems += "<option value='" + student.Value + "'>" + student.Text + "</option>";
      });
      $('#StudentID').html(stuitems);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: There is no need for 2 `change` functions, and the asynchronous behaviour of `getJSON` will mean the `items` variable will behave weirdly how you currently have it

Comment: @Jamiec I don't understand. Interesting issue. Can you explain?

Comment: Sure, you set items to "x", then make an async call. Immediately thereafter items is set to "y" and another async call is made. There is no telling in which order the async calls will resolve, yet in both you mutate the items variable. Whichever async call resolves last will have the options from the first and second async call. Hard to demo with ajax calls, but check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g1ekwg9u/) using `setTimeout` calls to make calls async

Comment: @Jamiec Super awesome! Check now.

Comment: Better, but in all honesty there is no need for either variable to exist outside of the callback, see my answer.

Comment: Yup. That's **the** best. If I add that, your answer = my answer! So let me leave like this and vote yours up!

Comment: Thanks, there is one other side effect of your code: when the page loads both selects will have a "Select Subject" option first, yet when `DepartmentID` is changed they will get re-popualted without the "Select Subject" option.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar  Jamiec's answer is working. I implemented that code in my application and it works.